# How can I replace Wordpress standard process of editing posts with making Wordpress use a custom page?

Tags: posts

I have the following problem: When I want to edit the content of posts, Wordpress simply opens its standard page editor where I can add and arrange blocks, control the general page design and what not. That page editor comes with tons of controls and in my case also all kinds of additional parameter areas for various plugins (like Yoast SEO and Content Egg etc), so it looks kind of cluttered or freightened with many elements not needed when you simply want to edit a post's content. Only among others can I edit the post content (text) there.

What I would like Wordpress to do is to open a custom page where I can just edit the post content (text) and submit the changed text back to the underlying database.

So how would I go about directing Wordpress to opening some custom page I have created where I can simply edit the post content, without all the editing facilities of Wordpress around?

The custom post editing page would probably a form with a message field where I can edit and submit the post content. How exactly would I need to build that form so that the (edited) post content is stored back into the database when I click on the form's submit button?

Comment: Install [classic editor](https://wordpress.org/plugins/classic-editor/), this brings back the old wysiwyg instead of gutenberg. in the settings panel you can switch between them as needed